# Install software on multiple ec2 instances along with json file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-ssm

I need to install Fire Eye in multiple ec2 instances in my AWS account, all running Windows Server 2012. I have the installer msi and could do it using Distributor in SSM. However there is a json file that needs to be in the same folder as the msi file when software is being installed. This doesn't seem to be supported by Distributor.

Can anyone help me out with how this can be done, short of logging in to every server and installing it manually after copy pasting the json and msi file in one folder?

Answer (score 0):

Usually for ad-hoc execution of commands on a fleet of instances you would use [AWS Systems Manager Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html):

> Administrators use Run Command to perform the following types of tasks on their managed instances: install or bootstrap applications, build a deployment pipeline, capture log files when an instance is terminated from an Auto Scaling group, and join instances to a Windows domain, to name a few.

Comment: I need to have 2 files transferred from say an s3 bucket to a single folder in every ec2 instance and then the installation command needs to be executed. How do I get files transferred using SSM Run Command?

Comment: @RameshMenon Using regular aws cli commands. The SSM Run Command allows you to execute regular scripts on your instance.